# procedure for getting a good healty records for playpen

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working as a junior oracle developer ... Now I am getting problem... My lead had asked to write a query or procedure for getting a good healthy records for  playpen ?

This is query ... how can i get all the Values ? I need output like **a a1 c s n**

```
create table t1
(c1 varchar,
 c2 varchar,
 c3 varchar,
 c4 varchar,
 c5 varchar
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
('a','a1',NULL,NULL,NULL),
('a','a1','c',NULL,NULL),
('a','a1',NULL,'s',NULL),
('a','a1',NULL,NULL,'n');
```

Comment: Removed `postgresql` tag as this is apparently only about Oracle - although the `insert` statement shown is invalid for Oracle.

Comment: why not 'b' instead of 'a' for first column ?